Installing intelij plugins into android studio, when studio crashes on startup
I just downloaded new components, Android Studio, IntelliJ Community, updated Gradle, Java, JRE, JDK (--version 22)... put it all into a new clean directory.  Made sure the environments from past javacs were gone, JAVA_HOME path updated, classpath updated... (all working except studio, crashes on start with the below).
I tried individual installs and running the Android Studio installer, hoping the presence of the above would address the issue.
Hoping there is a config or XML file entry to make manually that will allow studio to startup where and the directions above will work. The issue tracker is kinda useless, it only tells me what I know, but not where to put a config entry that will address the crash itself.
Thanks in advance
=== begin ===
Internal error. Please refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708

com.intellij.ide.plugins.EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.kt:577)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.kt:644)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invokeSuspend(PluginManagerCore.kt:830)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invoke(PluginManagerCore.kt)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invoke(PluginManagerCore.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span(tracer.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main$startApp$2$1$1.span(Main.kt:92)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.CoroutineTracerShim.span$default(CoroutineTracerShim.kt:31)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins$intellij_platform_core_impl(PluginManagerCore.kt:829)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:377)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
D:\AS\2024\jbr
=== end===


Please remove this plugins in this directory.
${user.home}\.AndroidStudio\config\plugins

And then restart your IDE.

HI Bill. Thanks for the answer.  Something wierd with this, ${user.home} is not set (least as near as I can tell from windows. I checked with both powershell (dir env:) and from a command prompt (set:).  Also, a dir /s/p on both drives indicates not found for ".AndroidStudio" .  I also searched regedit (keys, values,data) for .AndroidStudio.

Did a little more digging.  found even though i directed paths to other than c drive, the installer still creates a google directory entry in appdata/AndroidStudio subdir. in there are some resource files and a ref to the bin dir where theres a couple of .bat files.  the issue tracker message data is reading from a json there with an xml .  none of the env is being set on launch.  removing the json altogether fixes nothing.

${user.home} - In Windows, C:\Users<your user name>.

Hi Bill, ya, i get it, it's not there.  I suspect somewhere down in the xml resources are the intellij references that  are being pulled.  I had to move on to other work.  I wont get back to the till the weekend or later.  I'll probably just go to another sys and try an all-defaults install on a new windows instance.  see what happens.  Ive used this box for a long time, it's registry, powershell env etc are probably a mess.  Pretty sure this is just a problem on my sys.

yes, if you reinstall android studio in new system, it will be okay.

Thanks for the tips on this.
I got it sorted.  I removed the appdata-google directory, and the install directory.
Then in the OS setup %java_home%, %classpath% , and adjusted the priority of things in path statement and ran reinstall.
Tip, if someone has history on their workstation with older java env's, make sure you remove system path and var references prior to install. Also, the sdk on install cannot create directories and has a dependency to not install in the same dir-struct as the studio. If you are like me and like to keep things together, make sure you pre-crete the sdk directories first.  Then run the install. Studio and env work well after that.  To keep older java resources around, just make sure they are deprecated in the path/classpath.
